# Axis web service can't be invoked from web application

Tags: web-services, axis

I have a simple axis 1.4 web service which I deployed successfully and can invoke it from main method of a Java class.

This works fine but when I try to invoke it from a web application it throws an exception saying 'Class not found' for the class 'ws/impl/AwardWebServiceSoapBindingStub'.

I tried to debug it but could not find anything.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Jani.

Comment: What kind of web application? Java? ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it.

It was due to a different version of axis being downloaded by Maven while building.

I excluded it from dependencies.

Thank you,
Jani.